# Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing, rxjs5, ngrx

I am using **@ngrx/effects** with **@angular/router**. (Angular 2 version RC4)

If I add this line `private router: Router` in the effects:

```
@Injectable()
export class RouterEffects {
  constructor(
    private updates$: StateUpdates<AppState>,
    private router: Router   // <- this line
  ) {}
}
```

I will get this error:

> EXCEPTION: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! (Token Application
>   Initializer -> Token @ngrx/effects Bootstrap Effects -> Router ->
>   ApplicationRef -> ApplicationRef_)

How can I solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Anthony @qdouble and Mike Ryan @MikeRyan52 on gitter.

https://gitter.im/ngrx/effects?at=57850fc0b79455146fa4236f

> Application initializers will be deprecated in the next RC. So it will
>   probably be fixed around then.

And Anthony's walkaround way is here:
https://gitter.im/ngrx/effects?at=576ff574bb1de91c546fde19